# Title class html

Tags: html, css

```
<title>{{ __('login') }}</title>
```

Hello,

I am creating a multilanguage website. I have json files to store language words. I store all words lowercase. And i have a css file like this :

```
.text-lowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase !important;
}

.text-uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

.text-capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize !important;
}

.text-capitalize-first:first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize !important;
}
```

If i want to change their text format, i add this classes.

I store lowercase because json file case sensitive, so i dont want to add `Login` , `login` into json file because i dont want to write two times. I only store the `login`. Everything works for all html but i stucked in title tag. Can the class be added to the title tag?

Here is sample :

```
<p class="text-uppercase">{{ __('login me') }}</p>
Output : LOGIN ME
<p class="text-capitalize">{{ __('login me') }}</p>
Output : Login Me
<p class="text-capitalize-first">{{ __('login me') }}</p>
Output : Login me
```

Comment: `<title>` like any valid tag can have any global attribute, `class` being of such. But it can only be within the `<head>` and anything in the `<head>` is `display:none`. That means any non-meta data features belonging to normal document flow. So having class on a `<title>` tag is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CSS doesn't style the HTML `TITLE` element. You’ll need to transform the text on the back-end.

Note that converting all of your text to lower case is a lossy conversion: you shouldn’t display people’s names, for example, in lower case.

Comment: Hi Peter, this all in front end. I am using Laravel Localization. And all words are static. But i write login four or five times in html and different format. So i dont want to write in json multiple format. Because i choosed this way. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Fair enough - I changed the word 'server' to 'back-end', because whatever your stack, there's probably a 'back-end' where you can write code. In this case, you can transform text using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have the ability to transform the text, based on your requirements, you're looking for a JavaScript solution. CSS is limited to the text-transform options that I'm assuming you've looked up at this point.

Here's an example of a library that might help: https://github.com/blakeembrey/change-case